# Lookup function for matching ID's and then populating an additional value - Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a data set:

```
ID Name Amount BID        BID 2
1  Jack 100     1          
1  John 200     *Blank*    
2  Tony 300     2
```

How can I lookup the ID and where the ID is matching look at the BID and find the relating ID value where the ID value has been populated for the same ID. I want the value to appear in BID 2 which is in column 5.

IE John should have a BID of 1 as his ID is 1 like Jacks ID.

I have tried

```
 =vlookup(A2,A2:C5,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: Is `Bid` always numeric?  Is there always only one cell per `ID` that has a value?  If not are the values always the same?  If not, which do you want?

Comment: Bid is always numeric, there is always an ID for each of the records, some IDs are the same as multiple people belong to the same team.

Comment: so the logic would be if any of the values in column A are matching then look at column D to check for a BID. If the BID exists for 1 ID then replicate this id for all other records where there are matches in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't know a way to do this through formula, but a VBA solution would look like this:

```
Sub FindTheValue()

Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Range("Z" & i).Value = "" Then
        For j = 1 To lastrow
            If Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & j).Value And Range("Z" & j).Value <> "" Then
                Range("AA" & i).Value = Range("Z" & j).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

[image: BeforeAfter]

Comment: Thanks! If the ID I wanted was in Column C and the BID was in column Z and the BID2 was in column AA, how would your formula change? I have tried to change this myself with no success.

Comment: @GeorgeH I've updated the code - swapped A for C, D for Z, E for AA.