# checking a value in column F and checking in Column G for a value existing

Tags: vba, excel

I am in the process of automating a day to day process. I have ID's in column F and ID2's in column G. How could I write a VBA for filling in the blanks if the IDs in column F are the same? IE ID 123 will always have the ID of 1. In some cases the ID to be used is not the one from above.

Test data:

```
ID       ID2
123      1
123      *Blank*
456      56
456      *Blank*
456      *Blank*
789      23
```

I have utilized some existing stackoverflow code and tried to adapt it for my needs.
Code:
     Sub FindingtheBID()

```
 Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

 Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roots data")
 lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To lastrow
  If Range("G" & i).Value = "" Then
    For j = 1 To lastrow
        If Range("C" & i).Value = Range("F" & j).Value And Range("G" & 
     j).Value <> "" Then
            Range("H" & i).Value = Range("G" & j).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
 End If
 Next i
  End Sub
```

Comment: The suggested alternative is not suitable for me unfortunately

Comment: Why not?  Please put what you have tried so we can help overcome the specific problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added some code which I have tried to adapt for my needs.

Comment: Why not sort the two columns first on F then on G and use the load from above?  It will be quicker than looping.

Comment: I have tried this when I tried originally and the excel goes into a none responsive state.

Comment: Post the code you used which was non responsive.

Comment: I am unable to do fill from above because some of the values will be 0 and they will not have a matching value in the column to the left.
Sub split()
    Dim columnValues  As Range, i As Long

    Set columnValues = Selection

    For i = 1 To columnValues.Rows.Count
        If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = columnValues.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Is this not a duplicate? I am sure i basically answered this question already though I deleted my answer when the question started to be changed. This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015763/lookup-function-for-matching-ids-and-then-populating-an-additional-value-vloo

Comment: Your title says A & B then you refer to F & G. You changed the requirements in the last question so I am not posting my answer again (or making the minor amendment) unless this is clarified as what you actually want with the final columns.

Comment: Hi, I have just changed the question to reflect what I am looking for. In regards to the other question, I went with the other answer as it was easier to interpret. I am new to VBA, so looking to learn skills that I can use with other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like as follows? I need to do a quick syntax check on other machine.

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roots data")

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Dim dataArr()

dataArr = ws.Range("F1:G" & lastRow).Value
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim dict As Object

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For currentRow = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)

    If Not IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 2)) And Not dict.exists(dataArr(currentRow, 1)) Then
        dict.Add dataArr(currentRow, 1), dataArr(currentRow, 2)
    End If

Next currentRow

For currentRow = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)

    If IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 2)) Then

        dataArr(currentRow, 2) = dict(dataArr(currentRow, 1))

    End If

Next currentRow

ws.Range("F1").Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1), UBound(dataArr, 2)) = dataArr

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, with this I get subscript out of range when I run the program on line:
      If Not IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 4)) And Not dict.Exists  (dataArr  (currentRow, 1)) Then

Comment: on which line is it?

Comment: Did you check the code above? Sorry, I updated almost immediately after posting and the 4 become a 2.  I should have made clearer. My bad.

Comment: Hi, I have accepted your answer it has worked very well. Thank you for your patience!